# Как выполнить несколько INSERT с результатом SELECT?

Tags: mysql

Как добавить несколько строк в таблицу если одно из значений будет полученно из `SELECT`? В запросе все значения не меняются кроме, `product_id`.

```
 INSERT INTO `s_products_categories`(`product_id`, `category_id`, `position`
        VALUES ( *Результат SELECT* ,253,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете в списке селекта указать поля или значения

```
INSERT INTO `s_products_categories`
    (`product_id`, `category_id`, `position`)
    select `id_field_name`, 253, 1 from `table_name`
```